# REACT ERROR: Access is denied. Access is denied

Tags: javascript, sql

I keep seeing this error in my SQL database for a JavaScript script I'm working on. The problem is I can't find anything about it online (quote-searching it literally returns nothing) and there's no clue as to what in my code might be causing it.

```
"REACT ERROR: Access is denied.  Access is denied.   : USERAGENT :Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"
```

Does anyone know what this refers to and how to fix it?

Comment: When you say you're seeing the error in your SQL database, what exactly do you mean? I assume the error message isn't actually in a field in the database?

Comment: Also, when you say you're searching for the error, do you mean you're searching for the whole thing, including your user agent? It doesn't seem that surprising that there's nobody else experiencing this error who also happens to have the exact same combination of whatever those .NET versions are about as you, but there seem to be a lot of results if you just search for "REACT ERROR: Access is denied.  Access is denied."